# Google Cloud SQL not connecting via ipv6 from mysqlworkbench on mac

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench, ipv6, google-cloud-sql

- Created a Google Cloud SQL instance.
- Authorized my public IP to access the instance.
- Created user with a password to use it.
- Assigned IPv4 address to it.

I'm able to connect with the IPv4 address,
but not able to connect with the default IPv6 address.

I'm on Mac OSX Yosemite, 10.10.5 and my MySQLWorkbench is 6.2.4 (also tried with 6.3).

Any possible reason why I'm able to connect with IPv4 but not IPv6?

Comment: How are you assigning the IPv6 address (static, SLAAC, DHCPv6)? Also, you should understand that your OS may be changing you IPv6 address at different times for security, too.

Comment: The IPv6 is the one assigned automatically by google cloud.  I'm not assigning it or changing it.

Comment: I mean the IPv6 address from which you are trying to connect.  You need an IPv6 address on your Macintosh to connect to another IPv6 device. How did you assign the IPv6 address on your Macintosh?

Comment: ok, I didn't know that.  let me check how to setup an ipv6 address on my mac.  Thank you.

Comment: Just like you connect IPv4-to-IPv4 addresses, you need to connect IPv6-to-IPv6 addresses. Your ISP needs to support IPv6 and issue you an IPv6 prefix from which your IPv6 addresses originate. If you have IPv6 Privacy Extensions enabled on your Macintosh, your source IPv6 address will periodically change, and that could be a problem for your connection. Don't try to use Link-Local IPv6 addresses (start with `fe80:`). You will need Global IPv6 addresses (start with `2xxx:` or `3xxx:`).

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer.  I understand a little more.  For now I'll  work with ipv4.  Anyways, even with ipv4 google cloud sql seems to have connectivity issues from a gae app that I'll have to resolve first.

Comment: OK. I will put it into an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you connect IPv4-to-IPv4 addresses, you need to connect IPv6-to-IPv6 addresses. Your ISP needs to support IPv6 and issue you an IPv6 prefix from which your IPv6 addresses originate. If you have IPv6 Privacy Extensions enabled on your Macintosh, your source IPv6 address will periodically change, and that could be a problem for your connection. Don't try to use Link-Local IPv6 addresses (start with `fe80:`). You will need Global IPv6 addresses (start with `2xxx:` or `3xxx:`).